# Import module error but tree seems correct

Tags: python, import, module

```
cambridge_loader
├── CambridgeLoader.py
├── CambridgeSample.csv
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
```

I'm trying to run the `__main__.py` script but it seems to be running through some errors importing my class.

Inside `__main__.py` I'm importing my class like this:

`from cambridge_loader.CambridgeLoader import CambridgeLoader`

and `CambridgeLoader.py` has a class called `CambridgeLoader`:

```
class CambridgeLoader(object):

    """Parses an incoming Cambridge Benchmark CSV file and transforms/adds a few fields so that it can be consumed by RAP.
    """
```

When trying to run my `__main__.py` script and pass it a file to parse, I get the following error:

```
    from cambridge_loader.CambridgeLoader import CambridgeLoader
ImportError: No module named 'cambridge_loader'
```

Is the import of the module incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. My guess is that you run `__main__.py` from within `cambridge_loader`. In this case, python can't understand that there is a `cambridge_loader` package. You should run it as `python -m cambridge_loader.__main__` from the parent directory instead.
2. It's better to follow the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names), so that other people and you an a couple of months wouldn't have problems with understanding why the module is named in such a weird way.

Answer (score 0):

In `__main__.py` you can use relative import: `from .CambridgeLoader import CambridgeLoader`.